# Spring roo: Modeling applicant, application, universities and majors

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm new to spring roo. I'm supposed to develop an application where a user (Applicant) can sign up/in, fill in his profile details and upload some documents as well. After that the user may create an application. In this application the user must choose between universities and majors, each university has different majors. I want the majors to change when choosing the university.

I have the following model, but I think it needs some improvements.

Applicant.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Applicant {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String phone;

    private String address;

    @NotNull
    private String nationality;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "applicant")
    private Set<Document> files = new HashSet<Document>();
}
```

Major.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Major {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private int numOfHours;
}
```

University.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class University {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private String address;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Major> majors = new HashSet<Major>();
}
```

Application.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Application {

    @NotNull
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne
    private Applicant applicant;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<University> universities = new HashSet<University>();
}
```

What I'm not able to do till now is displaying the majors dynamically in the application when the user changes the university.

Example: 
University A has Major A
University B has Major B

When creating an application if the user chose university A only Major A should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Lock at [this post](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany) which explains how handle ManyToMany relations using JPA. I think you miss `mappedBy` attribute to make *University-Mayor* relation bidirectional.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but should the relation between University and Major be One-To-Many or Many-To-Many. The post focuses mainly on Many-To-Many  relations.

Comment: The type of relations depends on how many universities can be related to a Major and how may mayors can be attached to a university. This is a model design decision. In the same site you can found information about any aspect about JPA relationships: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships